# npm install from tgz created with npm pack

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I've created a `.tgz` file with `npm pack`. When trying to install it `npm` prints out the following error:

```
D:\tmp>npm install package-0.0.1.tgz
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\tmp\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\tmp\package.json'
npm WARN tmp No description
npm WARN tmp No repository field.
npm WARN tmp No README data
npm WARN tmp No license field.
```

It looks like `npm` for some reason does not extract the contents of my `.tgz` package, meaning all the `.js` files, `package.json` etc. although everything is there. Apparently it only tries to install the dependencies listed in my package.
Should it really work this way or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 14):

This error means you are not in a directory that has a package.json file and you are using the command that installs a package as a dependency into an existing, (local) npm project's package.json.

To install your package globally (just to test if it can be installed):

```
npm install -g package-0.0.1.tgz
```

Or, if you want to install/add it as a dependency to some other npm project (like a test harness), first make sure that npm project has a package.json, and then :

```
test-harness-dir> npm install package-0.0.1.tgz
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have the following project structure:

[image]

and you need to install `core-1.2.7.tgz` in the `libs` folder.

So you should run the following command in your project directory (test):

```
npm i ./libs/core-1.2.7.tgz
```

Once installed, your `package.json` file should look like below:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nolesh/core": "file:libs/core-1.2.7.tgz" <--- YOUR DEPENDENCY
  }
}
```